# How to create SPLink in Sharepoint 2010? Custom Type Field

Tags: custom-field-types

I'm creating a custom field that stores multiple link inside. The user control works, but it shows me the link like text so now I'm overloading the GetFieldValueAsHtml to modify the HTML..

How can I write down my link as SPLink? Every SPLink Properties is "readonly", so i can't understand HOW to do that!

I'd like to do something like that:

```
public override string GetFieldValueAsHtml(object value)
{

    string[] address= base.GetFieldValueAsText(value).Split(';');

    foreach (string s in address)
    {
        SPLink link = new SPLink();
        /*
         * MODIFY LINK
         * */
        this.FieldRenderingControl.Controls.Add(link);
    }

    //Code to convert in HTML my Control
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure so I'm posting a comment.. but couldn't you just use a HyperLink and set the Text and NavigateURL properties? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do in this method is provide a string representation of your field.

You do not need to add a control to controls collection. Sharepoint just takes the your string (html encoded) and puts on the web page. The string representation can be built by StringBuilder class.

Comment: Ok.. So you're telling me to add some "<a href...>" inside the string returned... But if i solve this problem this way everyone can see the links.. The thing i want to do is to swho only the link accessible for the logged in user! I guess SPLink could do that automatically!

Comment: Returning HTML code it prints it as is, no rendering as been applied!!! =/

Comment: If you want to do security trimming, you will need to do this yourself. I doubt using SPLink will automatically perform the security trimming for you. In fact SPLink isn't a control, so your code above shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Use SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode method to return HTML encoded string as I stated above.